# How to optimize the executable generated by a C compilation in Linux terminal

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

Is there any way to reduce the memory used by an executable generated with a command like `gcc source_file.c -o result`? I browsed the Internet and also looked in the man page for "gcc" and I think that I should use something related to `-c` or `-S`. So is `gcc -c -S source_file.c -o result` working? (This seems to reduce the space used...is there any other way to reduce even more?)

Thanks,
Polb

Comment: You might want to read the gcc documentation again. Are you really asking about `-Os`?

Comment: I suggest you to compile with the opimizations at the end of the code writing because, if you need to debug your program, in compile-time, CPU will re-order the instructions to avoid dependeces between them, and you will not be able to follow the running of the process.

Comment: ".. the memory used .." - it seems you are asking about the executable size *only*, i.e., the disk space it occupies. No compiler (yet) is smart enough to change the memory that *gets* used by the program itself. A `malloc(LARGE_NUMBER)` in it will always attempt to allocate `LARGE_NUMBER` bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [standard compiler option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html) on POSIX-like systems to instruct the compiler to optimize is `-O` (capital letter O for **o**ptimize). Many compilers allow you to optionally specify an optimization level after `-O`. Common optimization levels include:

- `-O0` no optimization at all
- `-O1` basic optimization for speed
- `-O2` all of `-O1` plus some advanced optimizations
- `-O3` all of `-O2` plus expensive optimizations that aren't usually needed
- `-Os` optimize for size instead of speed (gcc, clang)
- `-Oz` optimize even more for size (clang)
- `-Og` all of `-O2` except for optimizations that hinder debugging (gcc)
- `-Ofast` all of `-O3` and some numeric optimizations not in conformance with standard C. Use with caution. (gcc)

Comment: Interesting. I know this from gcc, but was not aware this is actually POSIX. +1 for this information (Woe betide you if this is wrong;-).

Comment: @Olaf I added a link to the corresponding POSIX page, just for you.

Comment: @Olaf In [tag:language-lawyer] land you can never know if someone is just kidding or dead serious.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that's what emojis are for :-) But you are right; humor is not a universal human property - too bad.

Answer (score -3):

option -S generate assembler output.
Better option is using llvm and generating asembler for multi architecture. Similar http://kripken.github.io/llvm.js/demo.html

llc

here is example https://idea.popcount.org/2013-07-24-ir-is-better-than-assembly/

Comment: LLVM does not generate multi architecture assembler. LLVM uses LLVM IR as an intermediate language after the front end and before generating assembler. LLVM IR has not been designed as a format to be stored and distributed. While the IR is platform independent, front ends like Clang cannot generally generate platform independent LLVM IR. Also, how does this help to answer the author's question?

Comment: or using jit machine, gcc have jit